# How can I insert code into the pluggable.php file without it getting deleted after a wordpress update

Tags: pluggable, core-modifications

Regarding the code that is being inserted into the pluggable.php file: its a require statement that links to a php file that is used to overwrite the basic wp mail functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't. That's the answer. It's not supposed to be edited. What do you actually need to change?

Comment: As said in the description, we wanna overwrite the wp_mail function with our custom function, without needing to link the absolute path to the file that contains this function via the require statement in the pluggable.php, because it will be overwritten by the next wordpress update.

Comment: Well the point of the pluggable.php file is that you can just write a wp_mail function in your own theme or plugin and it will be used instead. This is actually explained at the top of the pluggable.php file. Have you tried that?